# For a discrete Markov process $X$, the probability that $X$ started in $x$ returns to $x$ is always positive. So, there are no absorbing states?!

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, brownian-motion, markov-process

Let

- $E$ be an at most countable set equipped with the discrete topology and $\mathcal E=2^E$
- $X=(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a discrete Markov process with values in $(E,\mathcal E)$ and distributions $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$

> If $X$ is right-continuous (with respect to each $\operatorname P_x$), then $$\lim_{t\to 0+}p_t(x,x)=1\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\;,\tag 1$$ where $$p_t(x,y):=\operatorname P_x\left[X_t=y\right]\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E\text{ and }t\ge 0\;.$$

Let $x\in E$. By $(1)$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $$p_s(x,x)>0\;\;\;\text{for all }s\in [0,\delta]\;.\tag 2$$ Now, the Chapman–Kolmogorov equation yields $$p_t(x,x)\ge p^n_\delta(x,x)p_s(x,x)\stackrel{(2)}>0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge 0\;,\tag 3$$ where $$n:=\left\lfloor\frac t\delta\right\rfloor\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;s:=t-n\delta\;.$$

> So, the probability that $X$ started in $x$ returns to $x$ after time $t$ is *always* positive.

That sounds weird to me. since it seems to imply that $E$ *cannot* contain absorbing states. But isn't

[image]

a counterexample? Is there a contradiction to the right-continuity or any other assumption?

Comment: Your example of a two-state Markov process satisfies $p_t(x,x)>0$ for all $t\geq 0$. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Note that we are in continuous time here.  A discrete-time Markov chain that jumps at times 1,2,3,... is not a (time-homogeneous) continuous-time Markov process.  To achieve that, you need a so-called "continuous time Markov chain" in which the time between jumps are exponentially distributed.  So I would interpret your example as a process in which the process sits in state x for a random amount of time (in particular, almost surely a positive amount) and then jumps to y.

Comment: $X$ in the question is a "continuous-time Markov chain" (more exactly, it should be called a discrete Markov process, since most authors preserve the phrasing "chain" for discrete time). How do you define the "time between jumps" and why is it exponentially distributed? Do you have a reference for a proof of this statement?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland $p_t(x,x)$ should be the probability, that $X$ started in $x$ returns to $x$ after time $t$. In my example, $X$ leaves $x$ after the first transition and never returns (with probability $1$). So, shouldn't we have $p_t(x,x)=0$ for all $t>0$?

Comment: You first correctly define $p_t(x,x):=P_x[X_t=x]$ then switch to a different definition, probably similar to $p_t(x,x):=P_x[X_t=x,\exists s<t,X_s\ne x]$, and finally you wonder why the former do not fit the latter. Let me suggest to consider that @ByronSchmuland's very first comment fully answers this and to close the shop.

Answer (score 1):

The catch here is the word "return".  You have shown that $\Bbb P_x[X_t=x]>0$ for all $t>0$, but it may be that all of the probability is due to paths that haven't yet left $x$ by time $t$. This is not incompatible with "return to $x$" (in the sense of leaving state $x$ and then coming back to $x$) having probability $0$, as in your example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your second sentence. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: In your example (i) $p_t(x,x)=\Bbb P_x[X_t=x]=e^{-t}>0$; but (ii) if we define $J:=\inf\{t:X_t\not=x\}$ (the first time the Markov chain leaves $x$) and $T:=\inf\{t>J: X_t=x\}$ (the first return time to state $x$) then $\Bbb P_x[T\le t]=0$, for all $t>0$.

Comment: What's exactly the interpretation of $p_t(x,x)$? I thought it would be the probability that $X$ is in state $X$ after time $t$ assuming $X$ started in $x$. But from your answer, it seems like, that $p_t(x,x)$ is the probability to *stay* in $x$ at least until time $t$.

Comment: $p_t(x,x)$ is the probability that the Markov chain is in state $x$ at time $t$, given that it started in state $x$.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. But if we assume, that the process of my example has started in $x$, then, once the process has entered $y$ at some time $t$, the probability to be in $x$ at some later time $s+t$ is $0$. What am I missing?

Comment: Your chain is special in that once it leaves state $x$ it cannot return.

Comment: Of course it is special, but it is one that satisfies the assumptions made in the question. So, shouldn't it be a counterexample? If $p_t(x,x)$ is the probability to be in $x$ at time $t$, then $p_t(x,x)=0$, for all $t\ge t_0$, where $t_0$ is the time $X$ entered $y$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29991/discussion-between-john-dawkins-and-0xbadf00d).